# Install program to Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, c, raspberry-pi

I am taking a computer science program in University. There is a style check program we use to make sure our C code is formatted the way the teachers want.

The procedure I have to follow currently is copy two python files into the directory of the file I want to check. The files are named "cpplint.py" and "styleCheck.py". So after copying them in I execute `chmod u+x styleCheck.py` and then I can run it with `./styleCheck.py`.

So my question is: is there a way to install the style checker on my Raspberry Pi so that I don't need to do all the copying and pasting? It would be nice just to be able to run the style checker with the `./styleCheck.py` command in any directory and avoid all the repetitive cutting and pasting.

Comment: Maybe you want to remote copy some file, e.g. using `scp` (with ssh); however you could install Linux on your laptop, run the checker on it, and copy the files to the raspberry when you are ok with them. See also [git](http://git-scm.com/)

Comment: Install the checker into the `bin/` folder in your home folder. Create it if it doesn't already exists. Make the checker executable and log out and in again if you needed to create the `bin/` folder. Now you should be able to start the checker from any folder by just typing `styleCheck.py`. Whoever came up with that filename should consider reading the Python Style Guide a.k.a. PEP8. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

What would I suggest ,although not a direct answer to your question, is tinkering a bit with the code and see if you can pass as an argument the location of your files. That way you could just go into the directory of you styleCheck.py and do "./styleCheck.py destination/of/your/file" without having to copy anything. This will also make you feel good about improving a university piece of code.

Keep in mind that you should do that only if you are familiar enough with python so that you do not break the actual checker.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is put the files in a folder, do your chmod once to make them executable and then write a quick shell script that takes the file location as a parameter. Then have it copy cp the files into that folder, run your tester and delete them upon completion.

This is of course option B, I would simply do what Martin said.

Comment: can you give an idea of what the shell script would be like? Thanks